# How to make two children of a flex container be next to each other when the first child is also a flex container of other divs?

Tags: css, flexbox

In the example below, the `Add Role` div is on a new line instead of being next to `Role 5`.

How to get them to be next to each other using css **without** them being in the same container (`.roles` for example)?

```css
.role, .new-role {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}

.roles {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.outside {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 15rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
   <div class="roles">
      <div class="role">
         Role 1
      </div>
      <div class="role">
         Role 2
      </div>
      <div class="role">
         Role 3
      </div>
      <div class="role">
         Role 4
      </div>
      <div class="role">
         Role 5
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="new-role">
      Add Role
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The area next to role 5 is part of that flex group.  AFAIK The only way to invade it would be to manually place 'add role' there with absolute positioning.

Comment: display: contents; to roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround to put the Add Role besides Role5 under Role4 you could use position like so (at least works in codepen)

```
.new-role{
  position:absolute;
  top:14.5rem;
  left:7.5rem;
}
#role5{
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: There is enough space next to `Role 5` for the `Add Role` element. The issue is that `.roles` has rectangular outer boundaries, and the question is if anything can be done to work around them.

Comment: Sorry, now that I understand what you want i've edited my answer. I hope it helps.